# Reading snappy parquet files on Windows causes python to crash

Tags: python, dask, parquet, pyarrow

I'm unable to read snappy parquet files via pyarrow on Windows.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
dd_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
dd_df.to_parquet("my_df.snappy.parquet", engine="pyarrow", compression="snappy")
dd_df_copy = dd.read_parquet("my_df.snappy.parquet", engine="pyarrow")
dd_df_copy.compute() #<--- This is where it crashes
```

I've replicated this problem in a clean Anaconda environment with Python 3.8.  After creating the environment, I ran `pip install "dask[complete]"` and `pip install pyarrow`

The error is:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  3.8.3150.1013
  Application Timestamp:    5ed53446
  Fault Module Name:    arrow.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5ebd3029
  Exception Code:   c000001d
  Exception Offset: 00000000007abfc7
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: d8e4
  Additional Information 2: d8e42c04b828d96accf490cd13472bea
  Additional Information 3: aebe
  Additional Information 4: aebe917bfb5c1b58e884baa1f9c3d3d2
```

Similar versions of the crash obtain when I try using `conda -c conda-forge dask pyarrow`:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  3.8.3150.1013
  Application Timestamp:    5ed53446
  Fault Module Name:    arrow.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5ecf56ac
  Exception Code:   c000001d
  Exception Offset: 0000000000521587
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: e863
  Additional Information 2: e8638a01b9fb70505b0604ef9b98f3c6
  Additional Information 3: 1e47
  Additional Information 4: 1e47c852f479606e071f3ea8f80878a1
```

Comment: If you are in an anaconda environment, can you please try and install the packages using `conda` instead of `pip`? This might solve problems.

Comment: I'll redo it just to make sure.  I only tried pip after failing with conda and finding google results online alluding to pyarrow via conda having issues.  Stay tuned.

Comment: On a fresh environment and ran `conda install dask pyarrow`.  Got the following crash log:
```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version: 3.8.3150.1013
  Application Timestamp: 5ed53446
  Fault Module Name: arrow.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 5ecf56ac
  Exception Code: c000001d
  Exception Offset: 0000000000521587
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7
  Locale ID: 1033
```

Comment: Would you mind trying the conda install with `-c conda-forge`?

Comment: updated with the crash log I got from that

Comment: A clue may be that the call to `compute` doesn't result in a crash if it's not a snappy.parquet file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating packages fixed this as of July 1, 2020.  I think it was a `pyarrow` update that did it.